# How to modify settings.py to use cloud datastore in Django 2.1 and Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to use google cloud datastore in my Django project. I am lost. I have two scenarios:

1. Running google cloud datastore with production database
2. Running google cloud datastore emulator

I have to use different databases for different apps. Like I am using mysql for the following apps. My settings.py looks like:

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/connectionnanme',
            'NAME': 'db name',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3307',
            'NAME': 'db name',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        }
    }
```

Now I do not know how to configure my settings.py file in order to query my datastore in both cases. Plus any other thing I need to configure it?

Kindly share your knowledge or any helpful articles.

Thanks.

Comment: looks alright to me, what error are you getting?

Comment: I just want to know, how to use google cloud datastore along with these databases. I don't know how to configure my backend to be datastore. Both locally on emulator, and on appengine.

Comment: yes. But I know how to do that. What I don't know is, how to configure or waht to put in databases in settings.py file to use datastore backend.

Comment: ok so what I understand that if you are running it locally using `python manage.py runserver` you want to use different database and when you are running it on production server you want another database settings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do that on Django. Django relationship with App Engine and datastore is...weird.

Your best shot here would be directly using the [Datastore library](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) as usual, and any time you run your local server, [set the environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#setting_environment_variables) so then you use the local emulator instead of the production database.

Comment: But how right database backends in settings.py to use datastore? As for mysql we have complete setting, I don't know how to configure it for datastore.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The Datastore calls don't go in the `settings.py` file, they go in other files (for example, where you do the actual calls to Datastore). If you aren't going to use another databases, just delete `DATABASES` variable from the `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a connection string you will need to reference that in your views.py (or anywhere you need to connect to db) and import the connnection string from your settings.py. Note: if you are doing this it is strongly recommended that you store sensitive data such as passwords in your environment variables. The 'default' database setting below is for a standard local db on your development machine. Note: the google cloud mysql proxy can be configured a number of ways see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip)

```
 #views.py

 from django.conf import settings

 client = settings.DATABASES['remote']['CONNECTION']
 db = client

 #settings.py

 import pymysql

 if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):     

     DATABASES = {
     'remote' = {
         'CONNECTION' = pymysql.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>,
                         user='<USER>',
                         password='<PASSWORD>',
                         db='<DATABASE>')
       }
    }
else:

     DATABASES = {
       'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'HOST': 'localhost',
          'PORT': '',
          'NAME': 'db name',
          'USER': 'user',
          'PASSWORD': 'pass',
       }
      'remote' : {
         'CONNECTION' = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                         user='<USER>',
                         password='<PASSWORD>',
                         db='<DATABASE>')

   }
}
```